# TestCase : how to access the test result?

Tags: java, junit, aspectj

I am doing aspect programming for my thesis. There I have access to the TestCase class. There when a test case method is executed. I want to get its result whether test has passed or failed. So that I can use that information. How can I get the test result programmatically ? Or in which class method and variable is the test result is kept so that I can access it via aspectJ.

Here is sample code :

```
    pointcut allMethodsRun() : execution(* *.*(..));
    pointcut testClasses() : within(junit.framework.TestCase+);


 after() :  testClasses() && allMethodsRun() {  
     System.out.println(((TestCase) thisJoinPoint.getThis()).run()  );
```

Here I can access the TestCase class but how can I get the test result after test method executes. Any Idea or question ?

ilke

Answer (score 0):

all results are stored in `org.junit.runner.Result`. result of each method is added to an initially empty result. the call stack is more less: Runner -> RunNotifier -> RunListener -> Result. they are in packages: `org.junit.runner` and `org.junit.runner.notification`

[here](https://github.com/piotrturski/zohhak/blob/1741f41c5596b3eea7e26bd0314e0aa2304abe63/src/test/java/com/googlecode/zohhak/api/ProgrammaticRunTest.java#L23) and [here](https://github.com/piotrturski/zohhak/blob/1741f41c5596b3eea7e26bd0314e0aa2304abe63/src/test/java/com/googlecode/zohhak/testutils/JUnitLauncher.java#L19) you can see how i did it to test my extension to junit

Comment: How can i access this result class. Is there a get method. What i want to do is accessing the result after test is complete. How should i get the result?

Comment: Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(TestJunit.class); is what i found. But i want the result of alrrady run test case. How can i access that testcases result class.

Comment: have you checked the link i've sent you and javadoc for Result?

Comment: In that links i found this code but i dont run the test. Junit plugin of eclipse runs the test. Runner runner = request.getRunner();
  runner.run(notifier);
  return result;  can you give more hint.

Comment: public List<Failure> More ...getFailures() {
79         return failures;
80     } of result can help but how can i get Result object of a test case?